# git-svn cannot rebase because of files that exist only in git repository, not in svn

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase

When I do a git svn rebase, it tells me that it had a CONFLICT (add/add) in a file that's not even in the SVN repository, I added it after my initial git clone. When I fire up meld, my favorite merge tool, I see two versions of the file, one more recent than the other. So I resolve the merge conflict by taking all the changes for the more recent version, and do a 'git add' on the file. Git status does not show the change staged for commit, and git rebase --continue says:
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

What's going on? What have I done wrong? Why won't this merge?

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you've resolved the conflict to the state that HEAD was at already.  When you see that after resolving the conflict and `git add`ing the file your `git status` is clean or `git rebase --continue` tells you there are no changes, it's safe to just move on with `git rebase --skip`.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I should have mentioned. When I "skip," it just moves on and does the same thing for the next git changeset. I can "skip" all the way to the end of the rebase at which point my file that doesn't exist in SVN also doesn't exist in git and I have to roll back.

Comment: (Just to check, you are always doing the skip after adding the file that you've resolved the conflict in?)  This doesn't make much sense to me - if you've done `git add whatever.c` and `git status` is clean afterwards, then the version of the file is definitely the same in HEAD, the index and the working copy.  Does the file appear at all in the output of `git log --stat` at the end?

Comment: 1) git branch svn   (2) git checkout svn   (3) git svn rebase   (4) <merge conflict> git mergetool -t meld <copy all local changes and replace all file changes with it>;    (5) git add lib/python/disk_subsys/atoms/Atoms.py    (6) git status <Atoms.py is unlisted>    (7) git rebase --continue <No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?>;    (8) git rebase --skip    (9) repeat whole process with each of about 100 changesets in my git repository    (10) At the end, lib/python/disk_subsys/atoms/Atoms.py does not exist.