# Grab the svn HEAD git commit number?

Tags: git, git-svn

In regular git I can run

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

to get the git HEAD revision number. How would I get the svn HEAD revision number instead?

I know I can manually grab it by looking at the git log for the last commit with a git-svn-id. 
Also, looking through the manual for log pretty-format there's a way to get the ref name (%d) which in the case of the HEAD svn commit shows up as git-svn.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell what svn version my git-svn repository is based on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154244/how-can-i-tell-what-svn-version-my-git-svn-repository-is-based-on)

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your solutions!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I do not believe it is a duplicate as I'm looking for the git hash and not the SVN commit revision number.

Comment: Sorry misread both posts. For Git use commit hash instead of commit number

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a hack and I welcome improvements but here's what I've got so far.

I've added an alias to my git config:

```
svnhead = log --grep=git-svn --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1
```

now I can call

```
git svnhead
```

to return the short git commit hash and I can pass it in to

```
git rebase -i $(git svnhead)
```

for example to interactive rebase everything from the svn head commit.

**EDITED 9/23/13**

I recently realized this can be done using rev-parse:

```
git rev-parse master
```

if your master branch tracks the SVN repo, or

```
git rev-parse git-svn
```

Comment: This might be a hack, but it is the same hack that `git-svn` uses. Per the man page: `git log --grep=^git-svn-id: --first-parent -1` (see the `CAVEATS` section of https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_caveats)

Answer (score 2):

`git svn find-rev HEAD` will give you the SVN revision number

`git svn find-rev r$(git svn find-rev HEAD)` will give you the git commit hash for that revision.